# Why does placing an entity in the POJO class using "select new" in JPA cause an N + 1 problem?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "simple_entity")
public class SimpleEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

}
```

I want to get some **entities with additional column** from the database.
To do this I created a simple Pair class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Pair<First, Second> {

    private First first;
    private Second second;

}
```

Then I prepared a query in JPQL that creates the expected result.

```
@Repository
public interface SimpleEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SimpleEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.example.demo.Pair(m, false) FROM SimpleEntity m")
    List<Pair<SimpleEntity, Boolean>> getRecords();

}
```

The query returns correct results, but there is a problem with additional queries.

[image: wtf]

**Therefore, I have some questions:**

1. Why does JPA work this way?
2. Is there any way to get this data in one query in JPQL?
3. How should I get the entities along with some additional data (I've seen the solution with returning Object[] but it doesn't look nice)?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: I believe the default strategy is LAZY LOADING which causes the N+1. You can set it to EAGER and check if it does not fire N queries for fetching additional data.

Comment: Because you should be selecting the columns you want and not the full entity. Apparently you do a `this.name=m.name` in the constructor (you are doing alookup) or later on. Instead you should really be querying for the columns you want. Also instead of writing your own pojo, I strongly suggest to use a projection, for which Spring Data JPA will then create a query with the appropriate columns.

Comment: @SternK Hibernate 5.4.12

Comment: @Amit how can I change the strategy to LAZY in my case?

Comment: @M.Deinum since I can select one column, why can't I select the entire entity? I have a mapper for the entity in the code so I don't want an additional POJO object

Comment: The entity is lazy loaded, leading to those selects. If you want the whole entity what is even the point of the DTO?

Comment: @M.Deinum Because I want to select an entity + some additional column, e.g. aggregating some data. For example, an entity representing a matchbox and the counted number of matches per box in an additional column. I have already prepared a mapper for my SimpleEntity, so such a solution would be convenient for me.

Comment: see if this helps - https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading

Comment: @Amit It does not help, the article does not even mention the use of 'select new' in JPQL.

Comment: Sorry @Jelly, will let you know if I find anything about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but I believe it will add some info to the discussion:

**Result Transformer**

As you marked your question as hibernate, you can use a hibernate result transformer (deprecated in 5.2, but 6.0 is still in Alpha):

```
List<Pair<SimpleEntity, Boolean>> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(
"select m as first, false as second from SimpleEntity m")
        .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Pair.class))
        .getResultList();
```

This assumes `Pair` has no-arg constructor and produces:

```
select
    simpleenti0_.id as col_0_0_,
    0 as col_1_0_,
    simpleenti0_.id as id1_18_,
    simpleenti0_.text as text2_18_ 
from
    simple_entity simpleenti0_
```

**Proper DTO**

Use a class that can be constructed via a list of fields, not entire entity. The query will behave nicely when you specify list of selected fields, not entire entity

```
public class SimpleEntityDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private Boolean second;

    public SimpleEntityDTO() {
    }

    public SimpleEntityDTO(Long id, String text, Boolean second) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.second = second;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

and modify your query:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.demo.SimpleEntityDTO(m.id, m.text, false) FROM SimpleEntity m")
List<SimpleEntityDTO> getRecordsExtended();
```

This produces:

```
select
    simpleenti0_.id as col_0_0_,
    simpleenti0_.text as col_1_0_,
    0 as col_2_0_ 
from
    simple_entity simpleenti0_
```

**General remarks**

I believe that one of the reasons of using DTOs over entities in projections is that they are not managed. In your case, where an entity is a part of a DTO, the entity IS managed:

```
@Transactional
public void changeValueInFirstRecord() {
    List<Pair<SimpleEntity, Boolean>> all = simpleEntityRepository.getRecords();
    SimpleEntity firstEntity = all.get(0).getFirst();
    boolean managed = entityManager.contains(firstEntity);
    System.out.println("managed: " + managed);  // true
    firstEntity.setText("new value");           // firstEntity is updated
}
```

The same is true in case of a result transformer:

```
@Transactional
public void changeValueInFirstEntityViaTransformer() {
    List<Pair<SimpleEntity, Boolean>> all = entityManager.createQuery(
            "select m as first, false as second from SimpleEntity m")
            .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Pair.class))
            .getResultList();
    SimpleEntity firstEntity = all.get(0).getFirst();
    boolean managed = entityManager.contains(firstEntity);
    System.out.println("managed: " + managed);  // true
    firstEntity.setText("new_value");           // firstEntity is updated
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, if Result Transformer is used or I do not have the entire entity in the DTO, this problem does not occur. 
I therefore have an additional question. How would you solve the following problem in JPA: You have the Message entity and the Like entity. Your task is to select all Message entities and the total number of likes. What solution would you prefer? How do you usually deal with such problems?

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing your app and your model, but in general: this seems like some kind of report, so using a dto may be appropriate - you really don’t need dirty checking etc in this case. Also, think if you need to pull all messages - is pagination appropriate? Can you use keyset pagination?

Comment: It's not even a report, just additional information (displaying the number of likes next to the post). Personally, I usually created a database view that aggregated such data, namely: message_id + count (like.id), but I wonder if it's better to just use JPQL and projection or DTO. (Paging is of course necessary)

Comment: If you have an option to use the view, which supports your querying patterns, by all means use it.